# Clicking on Marker icon has to show details view in bottom of Screen in android?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-maps, google-maps-markers

In Map it shows multiple markers clicking on each marker icon has to show detailed View at the bottom of the screen like one shown in image.
I tried like clicking on marker has to show a dialog which will appear from bottom by specifying gravity to that dailog. But the way I tried does not match well.

[image]

I'm using Eclipse not android studio. Anyone Please suggest me solution to get that view .Can anyone please share code or link would be helpful?

Comment: You can try to use `AndroidSlidingUpPanel` [here](https://github.com/umano/AndroidSlidingUpPanel). It will show some details at the bottom of your google map

Comment: Thanks for the reply @bjiang But i dont want to use android studio(Material design) can you tell me how to do in eclipse.